# How to apply a function to a DataFrame as part of a separate function

Tags: python, regex, pandas, function, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to apply a regex function to a DataFrame, which replaces a date formatted cell with a string taken from some of the characters.

I am having a problem getting the function to be applied to the dataframe itself.

This is my code so far:

```
def preprocess_test_data(self, test_df):

        def to_month_day(s):
            m = re.match("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", s)
            if m:
                return m[0][8:10].lstrip('0') + '-' + m[0][5:7].lstrip('0')
            return s

        test_df = test_df.apply(to_month_day)
        a = test_df[:,0].astype(str)
        b = test_df[:,1].astype(str)
        c = test_df[:,2].astype(str)
        d = test_df[:,3].astype(str)
        e = test_df[:,4].astype(str)
        f = test_df[:,5].astype(str)
        g = test_df[:,6].astype(str)
        h = test_df[:,7].astype(str)
        i = test_df[:,8].astype(str)
```

I keep recieving this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-a9f16326387d> in <module>
    183 
    184 # Dont change
--> 185 x_test_processed = my_model.preprocess_test_data(x_test)
    186 
    187 # Train your model

<ipython-input-10-a9f16326387d> in preprocess_test_data(self, test_df)
    119             return s
    120 
--> 121         test_df = test_df.apply(to_month_day)
    122         a = test_df[:,0].astype(str)
    123         b = test_df[:,1].astype(str)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

How can I reformat the dataframe so that it allows me to run the Re function.

Comment: `to_month_day(s)` method requires a parameter to be passed; did you missed that?Please do check once.

Comment: Unfortunately if I try this just by calling it normally, it then gives me: ```cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object```

Comment: Can you print out the type of `test_df` inside the preprocess func ? seems like `test_df` is a numpy array.

Comment: Anyway `apply` on a DataFrame will recieve `Series` values. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `test_df` being a numpy array and not a Pandas `DataFrame`. But even with a true dataframe, the function passed in the `apply` method will receive a full `Series`, by default a column, or a row if you use `axis=1`.

Here what you want (once `test_df` is a DataFrame) is:

```
test_df = test_df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(to_month_day))
```